# Why is $\prod_{i=1}^p(np+i)=(np+p)!/(np)!$, where $n\geq 0,p\geq 1$ are integers?

Tags: solution-verification, factorial

I checked on WolframAlpha whether or not if $(np+p)!=(np)!\prod_{i=1}^p(np+i)$ is true, but it indeed does. I spent a lot of time to verify it, but I could not do it because of what $(x+y)!$ would mean for $x,y\in \mathbb{N}$. However, in the end, I managed to figure it out by rewriting $j!$ into $\exp(\sum_{j=1}^n\ln(j))$ for $j\geq 1$, and then proceed it. The above formula is clear for $n=0$, so we may consider $n\geq 1$. Since we can write
$$
\sum_{j=1}^{np+p}\ln(j)=\sum_{j=1}^{np}\ln(j)+\sum_{j=np+1}^{np+p}\ln(j)=\sum_{j=1}^{np}\ln(j)+\sum_{m=1}^{p}\ln(np+m),
$$
we conclude that
$$
(np+p)!=\exp\Big(\sum_{j=1}^{np+p}\ln(j)\Big)=\exp\Big(\sum_{j=1}^{np}\ln(j)\Big)\exp\Big(\sum_{m=1}^{p}\ln(np+m)\Big)=(np)!\prod_{m=1}^p(np+m).
$$
Is this the correct way of proving? If not, how would you prove it?

Comment: It's just $\,(k+1)! = (k+1) \cdot k!\,$ repeated $\,p\,$ times and rearranged into a fraction.

Comment: You are overthinking. $(np+p)!=[1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot\ldots\cdot np]\cdot[(np+1)(np+2)\cdot\ldots\cdot(np+p)]$ The first square bracket is $(np)!$ and the second is your $\prod_{i=1}^p$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(np+p)!=1\cdot 2\cdot...\cdot(np+p)=1\cdot 2\cdot ... \cdot(np)\cdot (np+1)\cdot ... \cdot (np+p)\\=(np)!\cdot \prod_{m=1}^p (np+m),$$
So $$\prod_{m=1}^p(np+m)=(np+p)!/(np)!.$$